# Trusted web activity address bar visible after changing from github pages to netlify

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

So I have this project in GitHub https://github.com/joaopedrodcf/yokaidex

And was using GitHub pages and the address bar didn't appear in the application https://github.com/joaopedrodcf/yokaidex/blob/master/public/.well-known/assetlinks.json

But yesterday moved to Netlify and was expecting that everything would work the same way, but that's not the case. For some reason now when accessing the APP I always see the address bar.

I validated the certificate using: https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator and it says its valid, the certificate can be found here: https://www.yokaidex.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

So what I wanted to know is the reason why the APP is showing the Address bar even if the certificate is valid.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: Thanks, I think now is more understandable, the thing is that I want to know why even the certificate is valid it shows the address bar in the APP when it was deployed in GitHub pages everything was correct

Comment: On the Android side of the app, did you change the `asset_statements` data to reference the new domain?

Comment: Hi @andreban I didn't changed because It was already pointing to the new domain, 

```assetStatements: '[{ "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"], ' +
                        '"target": {"namespace": "web", "site": "https://yokaidex.com"}}]'```

The only thing I changed was the host and not the custom domain, but when I started using the Netlify to host the site it stoped working for no reason.

Comment: Can you try using `https//www.yokaidex.com` as the as the site in your assetstatements? The reason is that `https://yokaidex.com` and `https://www.yokaidex.com` are different origins, and accessing `https://yokaidex.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` actually redirects to the `www` version, which will cause validation to fail. The URLs being opened will have to use `www` in this case too.

Comment: It was exactly that! 
You're awesome!

Can you answer that for me to upvote you?

Thank you so much